# XML Query with a variable in WHERE

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, full-text-search

I have this code that works well. But I want to have a variable to change its value in run time. I want the output xml file in C#.

```
declare @MySearch nvarchar(50)
set @MySearch='بودان'

SELECT ID, Family
FROM Table_1
where freetext(Family, @MySearch, LANGUAGE 1025)
FOR XML RAW ('Employee'), ROOT ('Employees'), ELEMENTS XSINIL;
```

EDITED:

I ran this code and got this error:

> Null or empty full-text predicate.

I want the output `xml` file in `C#`.

```
declare @MySearch nvarchar(50)
--set @MySearch=N'بودان'    
SELECT ID, Family
FROM Table_1
where freetext(Family, @MySearch, LANGUAGE 1025)
FOR XML RAW ('Employee'), ROOT ('Employees'), ELEMENTS XSINIL;
```

Comment: If you want to initialize a `NVARCHAR` variable, you should **always** use the `N` prefix for the string literal! Use `set @MySearch = N'بودان'` to preserve the Unicode of your literal!

Comment: If you have the two minus before `set @MySearch` in your real code too, the new problem (according to your edit) would be easily explained :-) Anyway: If your code works with a given literal **with `N`and instead of your variable**, it should work with the variable as well...

Comment: The second code does not work without "set @MySearch..". I want to use the xml file in C#. A user can enter any thing for search but 'بودان' is constant.

Comment: Hi @user2111639, if you add a `@Shnugo` into your comment, I'd be alerted and could answer more quickly. And sorry, I do not understand the (new?) problem: If you do not set your variable to any value, you cannot search for it. This seems rather obvious... If the given value is *constant* why not put it in the right place  as a constant value? So: Where is this value used and where is an (additional?) user input used?

Comment: So the only way is to connect with the database? Through XML file could not perform the operation? for example: `string cmdString = @"select * FROM Table_1 where freetext(Family, '""*"+searchStr+ @"*""', LANGUAGE 1025)";`

Comment: @user2111639, again: Without the `@Shnugo` in your comment there'll be no alert... And also again: I do not understand what you want... If you want to run a `SELECT` you must be connected with the database... What else? How do you want to *perform the operation through XML file*? If you call this from C# you should learn to use parameters. But this runs into a totally new question...  My suggestion: Close this question by acception my answer (if the original issue is solved) and - if you like my answer - vote it up. Then start a new question to avoid a chameleon question...

Comment: Thank you @Shnugo. How do I ask my new question (that is, my new title for my new question)?

Comment: @user2111639, great, got the alert :-) You new question is something like *How do I call a `SELECT` statement with parameters from C#. But - to be honest - if you search for this, you'll find many questions with answers. So start with some research, look for classes like `SqlCommand`, learn how to add parameters with type and value. And - if you really start a new question - place a link here (with a `@Shnugo`). I'll try to help you again. And - if you want so - it would be kind to tick the acceptance check below the vote counter if this issue is solved. Happy coding!

Comment: @Shnugo, We cannot create an xml file from parameters and variables without setting a value for them, can we? Therefore, we must connect to database in C#. OK?

Comment: @user2111639 sorry, this is absolutely not clear... It does not matter what kind of `SELECT` you are calling, wheter it returns table data or an XML. It will be something like `SELECT Something FROM SomeWhere WHERE SomeValue=@YourParam;` - if needed you can add `FOR XML ...`. Now your problem is to set the value of the parameter? You are calling this from C#, don't you? The `SqlCommand` has a list of `Parameters`. You add the params needed and call it. Of course you must be connected with the DB to do this...

Comment: OK. Thank you. My answer was this sentence: Of course you must be connected with the DB to do this.

Comment: Hello @Shnugo. Please post this answer that I tick it as answered. "...... Of course you must be connected with the DB to do this." Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "N" makes the difference, and you need it twice...

Try this:

```
DECLARE @v1 VARCHAR(10)='بودان';
DECLARE @v2 VARCHAR(10)=N'بودان';
DECLARE @nv1 NVARCHAR(10)='بودان';
DECLARE @nv2 NVARCHAR(10)=N'بودان';

SELECT @v1,@v2,@nv1,@nv2;
```

The result

```
?????   ?????   ?????   بودان
```

Only the very last attempt will show what you need...

The reason: A *normal* string `SET @v='MyString'` is **not handled as UNICODE**

It is neither enough to declare the variable as `NVARCHAR` nor is it enough to store a unicode literal like `N'SomeText'`.

### EDIT:

After long disucussion in comments the final sentence to solve the issue was this:

Of course you must be connected with the DB to do this!

What ever you want to with your database, first you need an opened connection.